# "[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known" when using django-ses

Tags: django, amazon-ses, django-ses

I'm trying to plug django-ses into my project. I've followed instructions laid out in this tutorial:
https://kholinlabs.com/the-easiest-way-to-send-emails-with-django

Although I believe I've followed these closely, when sending a test email I receive this error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I've successfully registered with SES and validated the email I'm using to send.

The error occurs either when sending from the python console or from the app.

These are my relevant settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '{secret key}'
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '{secret access key}'
AWS_SES_AUTO_THROTTLE = 0.5
```

How can I fix this?

**Command used to send emaik**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

**Full stack trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/app/letters/management/commands/test_email.py", line 19, in handle
    fail_silently=False,
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_ses/__init__.py", line 157, in send_messages
    rate_limit = self.get_rate_limit()
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_ses/__init__.py", line 247, in get_rate_limit
    quota_dict = self.connection.get_send_quota()
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/ses/connection.py", line 341, in get_send_quota
    return self._make_request('GetSendQuota')
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/ses/connection.py", line 102, in _make_request
    data=urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/user/python-venvs/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/https_connection.py", line 119, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I worry that you have to debug it, set break point at boto3 source code to see the response from AWS. They're not categorize the error message so that's really hard to say something. Or maybe you can try to connect to AWS with just boto3 only to see is there any issue with your AWS credentials or something.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I've managed to get a boto script running and I've come up against the same error :) "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known". But it leaves an additional message at the end of the stack, which I think is more revealing "botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://email.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/". Any ideas what that means?

Comment: That mean the endpoint doesn't exists. Which region you're setting up for your SES?

Comment: There are only 3 available endpoint for Amazon SES so you could try to find it in here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html, and then change `AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT` to the correct endpoint

Comment: Thanks again @ToanQuocHo - I can see a typo in my settings now, I've added the smtp part that was missing. I've been trying to verify that it's fixed, some sign of improvement, but the code is now hanging, it doesn't seem like SES is responding.

Comment: Yeah, I refer you to keep trying with boto3 only first. then when you're make sure that all your mailing configuration is all right then move a head to setup in Django. You could take a look at here, make sure that all the test passed before working with Django stuff: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Done! Thank you so much for your help. I verified with the boto script as you suggested, I discovered that I needed to verify the recipient address whilst in sandbox mode and that I had selected the wrong eu region, 2 instead of 1. Please feel free to post an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

This caused because your application cannot reach your mail server, there are some reason which might cause this issue, not properly configure SES, wrong email server endpoint, wrong credentials.

So you can follow below steps to figure it out.

1. Configure your SES (verify your emails/domains) and [get SMTP credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html). So at this step you've got:

```
Server Name: email-smtp.<region>.amazonaws.com (e.g: email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com)
Authentication: Your SMTP credentials.
```

2. Verify your SES configuration by [send testing email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html), follow these steps to verify that your SES was properly configure.
3. Set SES up for your application. E.g:

```py
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '{secret key}'
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '{secret access key}'
```

4. Test sending email on your application

---

There are something you might want to double check when you've followed steps above but still unable to send email:

- Your `AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` should be generated from IAM user which you use to perform step 2.
- `AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT` is one of these 3 available endpoint and match with the region you've choose to setup your SES:

> US East (N. Virginia): email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>
> US West (Oregon): email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
>
> EU (Ireland): email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did the reverse

> sudo scutil --set HostName 1.0.0.127

then

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

and added

> 1.0.0.127       127.0.0.1

tricking the system to return 127.0.0.1